# Systematic method to evaluate $\int x(e^x) dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

My calculus skills are pathetic. I haven't done the following integration exercise before, but this looks like it should easy to evaluate.

$$ \int x e^x\ \  \mathrm{dx} $$

I can probably guess-and-check my way to the solution. But I am looking for a more systematic, algorithmic method to doing this. The first thing I tried was

$$\mathrm{\frac{d}{dx}}(x e^x) = e^x + xe^x \implies xe^x =\mathrm{\frac{d}{dx}}(x e^x)-e^x $$

but how to go from here to  $ \int x e^x\ \  \mathrm{dx} $, if that's even possible.

Comment: I like your method. Try $xe^x$. The derivative is $xe^x+e^x$, wrong. But if we subtract $e^x$, that will fix it. So use $xe^x-e^x$.

Comment: Ah I see. Should have been totally obvious.

Comment: Integration by parts is the standard method here. But there is a lot to be said for more informal methods.

Answer (score 3):

Such a systematic method exists and it's called [integration by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts).

Comment: You beat me by < 1 minute!

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered **[Integration by Parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts)**?

Answer (score 0):

Use **Integration by Parts**. Essentially -

Let $u$ and $v$ be two functions *of x*. Then Integration By Parts says that -

$$\int uvdx = u\int vdx - \int u' \bigg(\int vdx \bigg)dx$$

- $u'$ being the derivative of $u$.

Now you need to be very strategic in choosing which function should be $v$ and $u$ because its always $v$ that is being integrated. I'll leave that as an exercise for you in the example you gave.